# Empty tspan not rendered / dy-value ignored

Tags: svg

I have the following sample svg:

```
<svg>
 <text x="0" y="10">
  <tspan x="0" dy="10">Foo</tspan>
  <tspan x="0" dy="10"></tspan> // this is completely ignored
  <tspan x="0" dy="10">Bar</tspan> // this is positioned 10 units below not 20
 </text>
</svg>
```

Why is the empy tspan ignored? Not even the dy-attribute is recogniced so the next line displays directly below the first.

How can I achieve a blank line (WITH a tspan because its all generated)?
I know that a simple space would fix it but I need a real empty line. Maybe there are some css hacks I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dy can actually contain multiple values e.g. `<tspan dy="1,2,3">abc</tspan>` Each dy applies to each character in the content so the 1 applies to the a and the 2 to the b etc.

If there are too many [the specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TSpanElementDXAttribute) that they are ignored.

> If more <length>s are provided than characters, then any extra <length>s will have no effect on glyph positioning.

Can you not change the generator so that every time there is a blank link it remembers the blank and adds the extra dy to the next real text?

Alternatively write a javascript function that iterates over the tspan elements and fixes them up.

Comment: The tspans here are used to define lines (as you may have imagined already). So multiple dy-values doenst affect me - still good to know. However looping over the children appears to be the best solution for now. However - the best solution would be when the tspan just didnt get ignored

Answer (score 4):

What I do is use a tspan containing any value (I use a dot) with a dy attribute and then hide it from view.

```
<svg>
    <text x="0" y="10">
        <tspan x="0" dy="10">Foo</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="10" visibility="hidden">.</tspan> // this won't be visible but will keep the space
        <tspan x="0" dy="10">Bar</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Visibility="hidden" works on Chrome, IE and Safari (haven't tested other browsers), whereas IE won't like opacity="0" and will ignore the spacing.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. In Firefox, `visibility="hidden"` keeps the space but `display="none"` works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/o84zhLe7/

Answer (score 0):

the `tspan` tag is made for grouping text characters ( for adding specific styles like `position`, `color` etc. ), it's dimensions are calculated based on it's content;

without content it will be ignored.

---

<strike>as a workaround you can try adding a line-break `<br>`:</strike>

```
    <svg>
     <text x="0" y="10">
      <tspan x="0" dy="10">Foo</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="10"><br></tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="10">Bar</tspan>
     </text>
    </svg>
```

---

EDIT:

since `<br>` isn't a valid SVG element you can try using multiple `dy` values (credit to Robert for pointing this out of docs):

```
   <svg>
    <text x="0" y="10">
     <tspan x="0" dy="10">Foo</tspan>
     <tspan x="-2" dy="20,10">&nbsp;Bar</tspan>
    </text>
   </svg>
```

or

```
   <svg>
    <text x="0" y="10">
     <tspan x="0" dy="10">Foo</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" dy="20">Bar</tspan>
    </text>
   </svg>
```

I don't know how you're generating tspans but you could probably implement this in the script quite easily.

Comment: adding <br> is not really an emty line ;). However are there any specifications which explain that behavior?

Comment: The specifications can be found at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TSpanElement. The dy attribute is a list of n lengths that are used to update the current text position just before drawing the first n characters of the text. If more lengths are provided that characters then the extra lengths have no effect on glyph positioning. In your case, you have one length and zero characters. Thus, the length is ignored.

Comment: One possible solution is to replace the dy with y in the tspan. For example:
<svg>
    <text x="0" y="10">
        <tspan x="0" y="10">Foo</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" y="20"></tspan>
        <tspan x="0" y="30">Bar</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>

Comment: Another possible solution is to remove tspan with no text and add its dy to the dy of the next tspan. For example:
<svg>
    <text x="0" y="10">
        <tspan x="0" dy="10">Foo</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Bar</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>

Comment: `<br>` is not a valid SVG element, so can't be used in an SVG document.

Comment: @BobbyOrndorff I integrated your suggestion to double the dy value to simulate a line-spacing in the answer, so far it's the solution that makes most sense .